# Class management in python

Tags: python, oop

I am working with python at the moment and wonder about something. I'm not too good with object programming, as I've always coded with imperative languages (C mostly).

So I'm asking myself.

Say I have an instance of class_1 called c1, declared this way:

```
c1 = class_1(bla bla bla...)
```

Say c1 has a heck lot of variable declarations inside, like

```
self.x = ...
self.y = ...
self.z = ...
#etc etc
```

Now, I have an instance of type class_2, called c2. Say c2 is declared INSIDE c1's **init**() function, like that

```
c2 = class_2(bla bla bla...)
```

Now, I wonder how I could... acces the objects of c1 from within c2?

Some could say I could make class_2 inherit from class_1. That's not exactly what I want in fact. The reason is that, class_1 should include in a logical way objects that are of type class_2, but class_2 needs to access variables from class_1!
If I would make class_2 inherit from class_1, I would always have to... declare class_2 objects in the external (to the classes) code. I want to work, in the external code, with class_1 objects. How can I reasonably do that? Starting to be a nightmare...

Thanks!

EDITED:

The context in which I use it... I have, as an assignment, to write a small space video game. I have to calculate trajectories in space. I also have a map. Some parameters such as acceleration, rotation speed, etc... Are specific to the 'map' : i.e. we design a map with obstacles and all, but depending on the map, the some physics constant vary.
I also have a 'physcis' class to handle different calculations related to the trajectory, position upating, etc etc.
So I just want to be able to use the many many many instances of different objects which are contained in the 'map' class, so that I can use these variables inside the physics class!
Is it legit?
Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is to pass the `self` from the `__init__` as an argument to `class_2`.  Also, your terminology seems a bit off.  If `class_1` is your class, `c1` is not a class, it is an instance.

Comment: `c1` and `c2` look like instances here, not classes.

Comment: yes, sorry, c2 and c1 are instances of their respectives class_2 and class_1 types, apologies

Comment: Can you describe a use case for this? If you describe how you plan to use these objects, we'd be better able to understand the relations between them and better able to suggest solutions.

Comment: Mainly, I want to know whether this is a has-a relationship (for example, `class_1` is `BinaryTree`, `class_2` is `Node`, and BinaryTrees contain Nodes) or an is-a relationship (for example, `class_1` is `Animal`, `class_2` is `Dog`, and you want to decide whether to return a `Cat`, `Dog`, or `DancingWalrus` without requiring the call site to explicitly call the `Dog` constructor).

Comment: Edited to answer your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question, each class_2 is related to a particular class_1. I'll call that class_1 the parent object.

You want to be instantiating a class_2 from within the parent, so something like

```
class Class_1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 # Your instance variables here
        self.y = 2
        self.class_2_instance = Class_2()

class Class_2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

is what you want. But you need to access stuff from the parent inside class_2, right?

Simply pass the parent into class_2:

```
class Class_1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 # Your instance variables here
        self.y = 2
        self.class_2_instance = Class_2(self)

class Class_2(object):
    def __init__(self, class_1_instance):
        self.class_1_instance = class_1_instance
```

And now you can, from within class_2, access class_1's variables.

```
print(self.class_1_instance.x) # prints 1
```

edit: You've clarified something about your question in the comments since I started writing this response, so now that I know what `c1` and `c2` are, I can show you how you would use the code I've written here:

```
c1 = Class_1()
```

`c1` will now have an instance of `Class_2` contained within it. That instance will be able to access all of the properties of `c1`.

Comment: Have chosen your answer, since you were the first to recommend this strategy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to pass a parent parameter into the `class2.__init__` and keep it  e.g.:

```
class class2:
    def __init__(self, parent, ):
        """ Create an instance of class2 saving the parent """
        # You might wish to assert that parent is type class1 here
        self.parent = parent
```

This will let you access class1 members from within class2 as `self.parent.member` which seems to be what you need.

Even if you can define a class within a class I would urge you not to - it would lead to unclear code and I suspect would actually have more of an overhead than you might expect.

You can define `class2` in the same file as `class1` and `class1` can either inherit from it or simply have members of the type `class2` but if you call your `class2` an underscored name such as `_class2_` then by convention you are making them private to the scope in which they are defined, in this case the file where they are defined, *(N.B. In python private is a convention - not enforced - more a gentlemen's agreement with the warning that private members **may** be modified/removed at any new version)*.

Note that defining a class is not the same as creating a class instance.

Just to see if it could be done I tried:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A:
...     class B:
...          def __init__(self):
...              self.b = 3
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.b = B()
...         self.a = 2
... 
>>> a = A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __init__
NameError: global name 'B' is not defined
```

This is because the rest of class A does not exist until **init** is finished, so class B needs to be defined inside the **init** before it is used -

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         class B:
...             def __init__(self):
...                 self.b = 3
...         self.a = 2
...         self.b = B()
... 
>>> a=A()
>>> a.b.b
3
>>>
```